# How do I build a regex pattern in JS that matches a string if it contains at least one "<" OR one "{"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build to a JS regex pattern that will match if the string either has a `<` or `{` in it, but I don't know how to use a `or` type of condition in the pattern. I know that `?` will give you 0 or 1 of a character, but I want at least of 1 of `<` or `{`

Comment: show the input string for valid and invalid result

Comment: What language are you working in? The concept you'll want to use is "regex union" but the implementation is language dependent so we can't give an accurate answer without knowing that.

Comment: the language i'm using is javascript and i've tried something like `pattern = /[<{]/; var str="<test"` and running the match I get null

Comment: @akantoword Add the input string(s) and the regex to your question instead of commenting them.

Comment: @akantoword I've added a note about usage as seems could be your issue, however I can't provide much help on language-specific usage without more information. Please provide a [Minimal Verifiable Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help.

Comment: @rtmh your answer has been sufficient, thank you :)

Comment: This is not rocket science, `[<{]` is all you need, why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets (`[]`) to generate a list of which the regex will match *any one* of the characters. Therefore, to match `<` or `{` use:

```
[<{]
```

For Example (Matched section in bold):

`[<{].*[>}]`

> **< This will match >**
>
> **{So will this}**

or

`[<{]`

> **<** Only the first bracket matches >
>
> **{** Only the first brace matches }

---

*Note*: Language and functions used are also imperative. Make sure you know how the function works so you know what to expect out of it.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is a link to MDN's documentation of Regexp.match which could be helpful. Also look at their 'see also' links for other functions and information.

Comment: it'll match as long as there is any ONE character? is that the default behavior even without the `?`

Comment: @akantoword It will match *exactly* one character. It will not match (as part of a larger pattern) if there isn't one or the other. The `?` would allow there to be no characters and still match.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `RegExp.test` function:

```
var re = /([<]|[{])/;

console.log(re.test("test{one<}"));  // true
console.log(re.test("test{"));       // true
console.log(re.test("test-->"));     // false
```

`([<]|[{])` - Matches either `<` or `{`.

Comment: Alternations is not a good idea since they have worse performance than character classes. Doing `[<{]` is much more efficient. Btw, you don't need to use character classes for `<` and `{` if you want the literal using `<|{` does the trick... although `[<{]` is better.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, that was for demonstration for the OP's *a OR type of condition in the pattern*.

Comment: Not saying the answer is wrong, actually is good. I commented just to add more details on the usage in case OP wants to move forward with alternations. Btw, you don't need to use character classes to escape the characters with `<|{` is enough

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, As for the performance, yes, *alteration* group could come to slower matching on big strings. But I've shown it as an alternative solution for simple input strings

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest so when would i want to use the alternations if [<{] works already?

Comment: @akantoword, an alteration group can have complex conditions like `([\w\.!?,\s-]+)|<.*?>|`. But your case in much simpler, and this `[<{]` should be enough for you. Anyway, in character class you can't consider a strict char sequences: let's say, we need to check if a string contains consecutive two-char pairs: `ab` or `dc`: `/(ab|dc)/`